# How to get log4j to log my firms classes only

Tags: java, spring, log4j

Below is a code of the log4j.xml file we are using at my firm. We been trying to change it to log only output from classes with made that is in org.xxxx.  can someone let me know if this can be done and how to do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="logs/disater_relief.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="rollinglogfile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="logs/ennrollment.log" />
        <param name="immediateFlush" value="true" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="1MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="3" />

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>

    </appender>

    <appender name="dailyrollinglogfile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="logs/ennrollment.log" />
        <param name="immediateFlush" value="true" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="datePattern" value=" '.' yyyy-MM-dd "/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>

    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="dailyrollinglogfile" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your root looger defines debug logging for all components. You should change it to `warn` (so you still see warnings) and add an extra logger for your own components:

```
<logger name="com.xxx.mycomponent">
  <level value="trace"/>

  <!-- appenders ... -->

</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="dailyrollinglogfile" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply turn off the logging for the package you don't want to see in your logs...

```
<!-- Limit JBoss categories -->
<category name="org.jboss">
   <priority value="OFF"/>
</category>
```